# Disable VBA popup when Copy & Paste

Tags: excel, vba, popup, paste

How would you disable those alert popup ?

The data size does not match your selection. Do you want to paste them anyway?

[image]

The clipboard contains a large amount of information. Do you want to be able to paste this information into another document later?

[image]

What I tried : `DisplayAlerts =  False` but the popup still appears ...

Comment: Could you share the code(s) that you're using when encountering these popups?

Comment: I just copy a range and paste it in an other workbook with Range("A1").Paste
Once its copied I close the workbook where i copied data from

Comment: I answered a question a while ago with error messages while pasting into merged cells. It is possible a similar change for your code *may* remove the first error message. For the second error message setting `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the paste should help out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933937/error-with-copy-paste-due-to-merged-column-cells

Comment: @Tragamor I also tries with this ^^

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/287392/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-the-clipboard-warning-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` instead of `DisplayAlerts = False`.

Comment: Another possible solution is merging the specific range, then write something to range.             Just like this: Range("A1:D1").Merge // Range("A1").MergeArea.Value = "Something Useful"

Comment: is merge doing same as paste ?